# Sorting C++, First element not working

Tags: c++

Please have a look at this code. It's supposed to sort it in non-decreasing order, but for some reason it puts the largest element first then the rest in the correct order.

```
int min(int start)
    {
        int minimum = list[start];
        int location = 0;
        for (int i = start; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] < minimum)
            {
                minimum = list[i];
                location = i;
            }
        }
        return location;
    }

    void sort()
    {

        int minimum;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            minimum = min(i);
            int temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[minimum];
            list[minimum] = temp;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried everything and it will not work and I'm about to go insane lol

Comment: can you share the entire program including the main section

Comment: should be issue with int location = 0 in min function. make it location = start

Answer (score 1):

@Slava explained why your existing code is broken and how to fix it.

I'd like to offer an alternative solution - learn to use standard [STL algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Such as the [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) algorithm:

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order

```
#include <algorithm>

void sort()
{
    std::sort(&list[0], &list[size]);
}
```

Even if you want to implement your own `sort()` logic (though `std::sort()` does allow you to pass in a custom functor to implement custom sorting), your `min()` function could use the STL [`std::min_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) algorithm, and your `sort()` function could use the STL [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>

int min(int start)
{
    int *found = std::min_element(&list[start], &list[size]);
    return std::distance(&list[0], found);
}

void sort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int minimum = min(i);
        if (minimum != i)
            std::swap(list[i], list[minimum]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int location = 0;
```

you initialize location to 0 and if `list[start]` is already minimum and `start` != 0 you return incorrect location. change it to

```
int location = start;
```

or you can use `start` instead of `location`:

```
int min(int start)
{
    for (int i = start + 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] < list[start])
            start = i;
    }
    return start;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I changed the part above it to list[start] and didn't even notice the location one.